# h2o4gpu does not run ensemble.RandomForestCLassifier on the GPU

Tags: h2o4gpu

I built a random forest classifier using the Sklearn Python API. After hearing about the h2o4gpu package for sklearn GPU acceleration I installed it and imported it. But the `ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` still seems to be running on the CPU. Am I missing something??

Answer (score 0):

Based on specified parameters Sklearn can be used as a fallback. Also you can force to use h2o's back end by 
`backend='h2o4gpu'`